# My vb.net 2017 no longer responds to <F4>

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Normally, I select a UI control anywhere in the designer view, then press  and its properties pop up.

A couple days ago, this stopped happening,  does nothing.
Alt-Enter still works and opens props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`.
- In the "show commands containing" field, type
  `View.PropertiesWindow`.
- Verify that the "Shortcuts for selected command" is set to F4 (Global). If not, place your cursor in the "Press shortcut keys" box, press F4, then Assign.
- Select OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the following instructions are for VS2017. They might not correspond exactly with earlier versions.

It's possible that somehow the keyboard mapping has changed. To check this try the following.

---

Click on Tools in the Visual Studio menu strip.

Click Options

In the text box of the Options Window type "Keyboard" without quotes and press enter. You should now see (among other things) a list of commands that can be assigned a keyboard shortcut.

In the text box labelled "Show commands containing:", type "propertieswindow" again without quotes and no spaces.

click on the remaining visible command which should be "View.PropertiesWindow"

Underneath that listbox is a greyed textbox that shows the keyboard shortcut that is currently assigned to it. It should be "F4"

If it isn't you can assign "F4" to it by clicking on the textbox labelled "Press shortcut keys and then pressing the F4 key. When you press it, in the greyed textbox below it will show what command, if any, the "F4" key is assigned to at the moment and now you can either choose OK to complete the reassignment or cancel to leave things as they are.